# simplify fractions

Tags: calculus

here is my equation

$$\frac{4s+4}{ \frac{4}{s^2}+\frac{16}{s}+8s+20}$$

Now I am trying to turn this fraction into a polynomial degree on the denominator and polynomial of degree 2 in the numerator. 
Everytime I attempt to factor out terms, I get a polynomial of degree 3. 
I even used the long division and did not work at all.
is there any way you guys can help me out to figure out how to tackle these kind of fraction? 
This is a transfer function of the system, and it has to be a polynomial of degree two. I used wolfram and it turned it into this ( which is what exactly I need)

$$\frac{s^2}{ 2s^2+3s+1}$$

but I have no idea how that is possible.

Comment: Thanks Archis Welankar for editing it

Comment: Your goal is not possible; the numerator will have degree at least 3.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $s^2$. Note then that $s+1$ divides top and bottom. That will let you simplify.

Comment: As the new numerator is a monomial, you can infer that simplification by the factor $s+1$ occurred. Indeed, $-1$ cancels the old denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a degree of two in the numerator, multiply by $ \displaystyle 1=\frac{s}{s}$.

This yields $$\frac{4s^2+4s}{\displaystyle\frac{4}{s}+16+8s^2+20s}.$$

Unfortunately, you still have a fraction inside of a fraction. You could also simplify out a factor of 4. This gets us to  $$\frac{s^2+s}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{s}+4+2s^2+5s}.$$

You can multiply by $ \displaystyle 1=\frac{s}{s}$ again to get

$$\frac{s^3+s^2}{2s^3+5s^2+4s+1}.$$

EDIT (Much thanks to Andre!): As Andre Nicholas so astutely observed: $2s^3+5s^2+4s+1=(s+1)(2s^2+3s+1)$.

Thus, we have $$\frac{s^3+s^2}{2s^3+5s^2+4s+1}=\frac{(s+1)s^2}{(s+1)(2s^2+3s+1)}=\frac{s^2}{2s^2+3s+1}.$$

You can use polynomial long division to factor $2s^3+5s^2+4s+1$

Comment: dear , I need it to be in degree two polynomial

Comment: The top and bottom are divisible by $s+1$, do the division and cancel.

Comment: $2s^3+5s^2+4s+1=(s+1)(2s^2+3s+1)$

Comment: can you explain how come you factored it in 2 second without using long division?

Comment: I used long division, sort of. I knew $s+1$ must divide the bottom since $-1$ is a root of the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply top and bottom by $\frac{s^2}{4}$ to get

$$\frac{s^3 + s^2}{1+4s+2s^3+5s^2}$$

which can be factored as

$$\frac{s^2(s+1)}{(s+1)^2(2s+1)}$$

Cancel out the $(s+1)$ term to get your result.

$$\frac{s^2}{(s+1)(2s+1)} = \frac{s^2}{2s^2 + 3s + 1}$$

Comment: nice work, how did you come up with this trick? can you explain the factoring part?

Comment: please show all steps, I appreciate it

Comment: please explain how you factored out the denominator so quickly without using long divion! the first one

Comment: @user65652 why do you think they didn't use long division?

Comment: This works by multiplying top and bottom by $s^2$ as well, but I used $\frac{s^2}{4}$ to make it look cleaner. I first tried just using $s$ to see where I got, but I didn't get far. Then after seeing that $s^3 + s^2 = s^2(s+1)$, I had a hunch that maybe the denominator had a factor of $(s+1)$, and it did. So it's not really a trick, I just had some hunches and $\frac{s^2}{4}$ worked out. I used wolframalpha to factor the polynomials.

Comment: @ sean, I don't know , they did it so quickly and I thought there is a trick involved for doing long division. long division takes time to do , I guess.

Comment: @user65652 Doesn't take long if you get a computer to do it for you!